# Is there a way to fix the assert.js:385 error in gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, assertion

I can't seem to get gulp to work, it wont compile and launh the local server as it should. I have tried downgrading, uninstalling upgrading and nothing seem to work. Am i missing something?

Error:

```
assert.js:385
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\thebl\fusion\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\thebl\fusion\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)gulpfile.js:32:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at execute (C:\Users\thebl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js:36:18) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```

Code:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./css*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error',sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./css/*.scss', ['sass']); 
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    var files = [
        './*.html',
        './css/*.css',
        './js/*.js',
        './img/*.{png,jpg,gif}'
    ];

    browserSync.init(files, {
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        },
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function() {   
    gulp.start('sass:watch');
});
```

Comment: Time to apply debugging: comment off everything and start tactically uncommenting things. E.g start with `gulp.task('default', () => {})` and see if that runs. (it should). Then expand it: `gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], () => {})` and if that runs. Then uncomment the "sass:watch" function but comment off its function body. Etc. etc. Until you hit the code that causes your error.

Comment: Search for your error on SO.  You'll get to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55033313/836330 which is part of your problem.  Secondly, `gulp.start` won't work in gulp v4+ so search for `gulp.start` issues too.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62183014/836330

Comment: Okay thanks, I will give that a try